# Is it bad practice to rebuild state objects when their properties have not changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I understand why React components expect props to be treated as if they are immutable. My question is about replacing objects that have *not* changed. Is it bad practice? Will it incur a non-trivial performance cost?

As an example, let's say I have a state that looks like this:

```js
let gameObjects = [
 { id: 'a', pos: {x: 0, y: 0}, name: 'alice' },
 { id: 'b', pos: {x: 0, y: 0}, name: 'bob' },
 { id: 'c', pos: {x: 0, y: 0}, name: 'charles' },
 // ...hundreds of objects
]
// pass gameObjects into functional react components for rendering
```

Now imagine I change only TWO positions but I rebuild ALL of the objects.

```js
gameObjects[0].pos = {x: 1, y: 1}
gameObjects[1].pos = {x: 1, y: 1}

gameObjects = gameObjects.map((obj) => {
  return {
    pos: {...obj.pos},
    ...obj,
  }
})
// pass gameObjects into functional react components for rendering
```

Should I go out of my way to re-build *only* the objects that have changed? If I understand correctly, doing so would prevent react from having to deeply inspect each object. However, I believe that even if I rebuild the object, React is "smart" enough to  *only* update the DOM if the nested properties change.

In my case, state changes will be coming from the network, so the code above should not be taken literally, but I am most interested in understanding the general case.

Comment: You may benefit from `Object.assign` over `=`.

Comment: You understand correctly.  New state object implies there will be a new render (the "function" of your functional component will be called again, for example), but that does not necessarily imply any changes to the DOM at all.

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple solution here, I think.
The only way you could avoid the rerenders is through memoization (useMemo hook). Or an external store of some sort with combination of some "hardcoding".

If you use something like this:

```
{items.map((obj) => (
    <Item key={obj.id} data={obj} />
))}
```

Then it's not going to work, since your one main object keeps on changing and all the children will update.

Now, in theory, if you had a fixed number of players, it would be doable.

[CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/recursing-shockley-v26dpy?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx)

I've added the Date.now() print in the component just to showcase if the rerender is happening. Also, used zustand here for a quick store, you can probably do context, redux, and pretty much anything.

Hope this can inspire you a bit and hope it can help.